# Run multiple cassandra nodes (a cluster) from the same machine?

Tags: cassandra, cluster-computing

How can I run 3 cassandra nodes (actually a cluster) from my Ubuntu? I don't want to create 3 instances of VMWare/VirtualBox but instead, configure each cassandra node to listen to a different port. Is that possible with one cassandra installation?

A solution that came to my mind is to have 3 local cassandra installation and configure each cassandra.yaml independently but actually I would prefer to have achieve that by my installed cassandra configuration files.

I need such configuration only for testing purposes, obviously.

Comment: This cannot be done by assigning different ports as some cannot be easily configured. However it is very easy to do this by using the synonymous addresses of the localhost (127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.2, etc). This approach is described in the answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22513979/setting-up-cassandra-multi-node-cluster-on-a-single-ubuntu-server/25348301#25348301

Comment: You say you don't want VMs but you could use containers (e.g. Docker) to get this working. This question is 8 years old so I'm guessing you have moved on by now but it could help somebody else since this is still the first page that comes up on Google.

Comment: @KNejad Any documentation on that? I am not familiar with Docker, so learning both Docker and deploying multiple nodes would be nice :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check this Cassandra Cluster Manager on github https://github.com/pcmanus/ccm

(link is to script that configures multiple Cassandras to listen on different localhost interfaces 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.2, 127.0.0.3)

Answer (score 5):

I guess it would be possible if you had 3 copy of the program, 3 different configurations where every port is different, and you'd have to exclude those ports from the possible connection sockets.

*Edit* I don't understand the downvotes. This is actually the simplest way to do it, have one set of binaries and create a set of conf and yaml files for each of your nodes, then use one launch script for each of the local nodes you want.

Example : Machine 1 on 7199, Machine 2 on 7200, Machine 3 on 7201 and so forth.
Use aliases for your localhost IP, 127.0.0.2, .3, .4 etc

Nodetool ring will work as intended, and show you a cluster, only all of them will be with the same root IP.

Comment: Probably the downvotes are because not all ports can be easily moved, some are hardcoded. Looks more bug than a feature of Cassandra but this requires some special workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

I've seem problems with port conflicts on a JMX library ?jamm maybe? before, that doesn't seem configured through the yaml, but maybe the launch .sh script can disable it, that appears to be a JVM option built up in the launch script.

There was also a trick with using a different loopback addresses for the server instances so they could coexist with the same ports, but that ran into the jamm problems. That was from the Packt cassandra high performance cookbook.

But as of 1.2.5 and higher, roughly, I have not been able to do this successfully.

Comment: This can be easily solved by setting a different JMX port for each Cassandra instance. This port is defined in conf/cassandra-env.sh, edit and it will work again.