# cassandra when I change the port, facing this issue Unable to gossip with any seeds

Tags: cassandra

If I change the port one of the cassandra node will it communicate to other node?

I am using cassandra 3.6 and 3 node of cassandra .

node1 and 2 having default port like storage_port=7000, rpc_port=9160 etc.
but I change the port for node3 given below.

```
storage_port:                   7005
ssl_storage_port:               7006
native_transport_port:          9043    
rpc_port:                       9161
```

but when I connect to cassandra with node3, this error I am facing

> Exception (java.lang.RuntimeException) encountered during startup:
>   Unable to gossip with any seeds

how to fixed this issue please help me out.

Comment: Did you restart all nodes in Cassandra after changing the port?

Comment: yes @soheil i restarted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setting up cassandra multi node cluster on a single ubuntu server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22513979/setting-up-cassandra-multi-node-cluster-on-a-single-ubuntu-server)

Answer (score 3):

The ports on all nodes need to be the same.

Comment: thanks zanson.. but node2 and nod3 in the same host, if i use same port then this will give me error port already using.

Comment: You need to give each host a unique IP, so if you want multiple nodes on the same host you need to get that host multiple IP addresses.  If you want to try out multiple nodes on a single host you can take a look at using ccm to do so: https://github.com/riptano/ccm

Comment: thanks @zanson 1 last question, can we assign a centos server with two diffrent ips.

Comment: yes, if you give your server multiple IP's then you can set each Cassandra instance up with its own IP.