# Multiple instances of Cassandra on each node in the cluster

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Is it possible to have a cluster in Cassandra where each of the server is running multiple instances of Cassandra(each instance is part of the same cluster).

I'm aware that if there's a single server in the cluster, then [it's possible to run multiple instances of Cassandra on it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22513979/5701173), but is it also possible to have multiple such servers in the cluster. If yes, how will the configuration look like(listen address,ports etc)?

Even if it was possible, I understand that there might not be any performance benefits at all, just wanted to know if it's theoretically possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible & such setup is often used for testing, for example, using [CCM](https://github.com/riptano/ccm), although it creates multiple interfaces on loopback (127.0.0.2, ...). DataStax Enterprise also has so-called [Multi-instance](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/multiInstance/multiInstanceTOC.html).

You need carefully configure your instances separating ports, etc. Right now, potentially using the Docker could be the simpler solution to implement it.

But why do you need to do it? Until you have really biffy machine, with a lot of RAM & multiple SSDs, this won't bring you additional performance.

Comment: Upvote from me; exactly how I would have phrased it, too (with the warning).  CCM has come a long way, and basically does exactly what he's asking.

Comment: Does CCM create multiple instances on multiple nodes(different physical servers), all working together in a single cluster, or, does it only create multiple instances on a single node?

Comment: CCM is used for deployment of multiple instances on the single host, but I referred to it because you can adopt the similar approach.
But I would recommend carefully think about using multiple instances on the single box

Comment: I had read how to configure multiple instances on a single host, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do that for multiple nodes(What will be the listen address, broadcast address for each of the instances?) Actually, we want to try this on an experimentation basis as we thought that our RAM is being underutilized in case of a single instance per node.

Comment: Currently, we have got just a 2 node cluster, each node having more than 150 GB RAM and couple of magnetic disks in each of them. Currently our project is in initial stage and hence we are just exploring several of the implementation options, later on, the number of nodes may increase and we may use SSD as well.

Comment: you should be able to use the same listen/native transport address with different ports - see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5400 for details.

Comment: It seems like the configurations are not really straightforward like in the case of running multiple instances on a single node. I'm assuming that I'll have to configure multiple IP addresses on the single network interface.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible even i have worked with 5 instance running in one server in production cluster.
Trust me still it is still running but the generic issues i had is high GC all the time, dropped mutations and high latency so of course it is not good to have this kind of setup. 
but for your questions's answer yes it is possible and can be in production also.

Comment: How many nodes did you have? I mean physically different nodes.

Comment: I have 2 data centre with 22 nodes in each and having 5 JVM running on each node.

Comment: It would really help if you can expand your answer to include how exactly did you configure the YAML file, mainly the listen_address, broadcast_rpc_address, storage port and native_transport_port.