# Setting up two instance Cassandra cluster on a single physical node (laptop with windows 10)

Tags: cassandra, cluster-computing, jmx, cassandra-3.0

My main objective is to experiment with a Cassandra cluster. I have a Laptop so my options are, as I understand, (1) Use some virtualization software (e.g. Hyper-V) to create multiple VMs and then run each VM with a Cassandra instance, or (2) Use docker to create multiple instances of Cassandra, or (3) Directly run multiple instances.

I thought (3) would be faster, and provide me with more insights. So I tried this (by following https://stackoverflow.com/a/25348301/1029599). But I'm getting strange situations when I see that I'm not able to change the JMX port. More details below:

I've created two folders of Cassandra 3.11.7 - one in C drive and other in D drive.

**For C drive folder**, I've edited cassandra.yaml to replace 'listen_address: localhost' by 'listen_address: 127.0.0.1' and 'rpc_address: localhost' by 'rpc_address: 127.0.0.1'. In addition, set seeds to to point to D-drive-instance as '- seeds: "127.0.0.2"'. I've NOT edited cassandra-env.sh to let JMX_PORT be the default 7199.

**For D drive folder**, I've edited cassandra.yaml to point localhost as '127.0.0.2' and seed as '- seeds: "127.0.0.1"'. In addition, I've edited cassandra-env.sh to let JMX_PORT=7200.
Surprisingly, when I'm starting D drive's cassandra instance, it's always picking JMX_PORT as 7199 and not 7200.

```
Log (relevant portion from the start):
D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\bin>.\cassandra 
WARNING! Powershell script execution unavailable.    Please use 'powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted'    on this user-account to run cassandra with fully featured    functionality on this platform. Starting with legacy startup options Starting Cassandra Server INFO  [main] 2020-08-17 17:31:21,632 YamlConfigurationLoader.java:89 - Configuration location: file:/D:/apache-cassandra-3.11.7/conf/cassandra.yaml INFO  [main] 2020-08-17 17:31:22,359 Config.java:534 - Node configuration:[allocate_tokens_for_keyspace=null; authenticator=AllowAllAuthenticator; authorizer=AllowAllAuthorizer; auto_bootstrap=true; auto_snapshot=true; back_pressure_enabled=false; back_pressure_strategy=org.apache.cassandra.net.RateBasedBackPressure{high_ratio=0.9, factor=5, flow=FAST}; batch_size_fail_threshold_in_kb=50; batch_size_warn_threshold_in_kb=5; batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb=1024; broadcast_address=null; broadcast_rpc_address=null; buffer_pool_use_heap_if_exhausted=true; cas_contention_timeout_in_ms=1000; cdc_enabled=false; cdc_free_space_check_interval_ms=250; cdc_raw_directory=null; cdc_total_space_in_mb=0; check_for_duplicate_rows_during_compaction=true; check_for_duplicate_rows_during_reads=true; client_encryption_options=<REDACTED>; cluster_name=Test Cluster; column_index_cache_size_in_kb=2; column_index_size_in_kb=64; commit_failure_policy=stop; commitlog_compression=null; commitlog_directory=null; commitlog_max_compression_buffers_in_pool=3; commitlog_periodic_queue_size=-1; commitlog_segment_size_in_mb=32; commitlog_sync=periodic; commitlog_sync_batch_window_in_ms=NaN; commitlog_sync_period_in_ms=10000; commitlog_total_space_in_mb=null; compaction_large_partition_warning_threshold_mb=100; compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec=16; concurrent_compactors=null; concurrent_counter_writes=32; concurrent_materialized_view_writes=32; concurrent_reads=32; concurrent_replicates=null; concurrent_writes=32; counter_cache_keys_to_save=2147483647; counter_cache_save_period=7200; counter_cache_size_in_mb=null; counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms=5000; credentials_cache_max_entries=1000; credentials_update_interval_in_ms=-1; credentials_validity_in_ms=2000; cross_node_timeout=false; data_file_directories=[Ljava.lang.String;@235834f2; disk_access_mode=auto; disk_failure_policy=stop; disk_optimization_estimate_percentile=0.95; disk_optimization_page_cross_chance=0.1; disk_optimization_strategy=ssd; dynamic_snitch=true; dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold=0.1; dynamic_snitch_reset_interval_in_ms=600000; dynamic_snitch_update_interval_in_ms=100; enable_materialized_views=true; enable_sasi_indexes=true; enable_scripted_user_defined_functions=false; enable_user_defined_functions=false; enable_user_defined_functions_threads=true; encryption_options=null; endpoint_snitch=SimpleSnitch; file_cache_round_up=null; file_cache_size_in_mb=null; gc_log_threshold_in_ms=200; gc_warn_threshold_in_ms=1000; hinted_handoff_disabled_datacenters=[]; hinted_handoff_enabled=true; hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb=1024; hints_compression=null; hints_directory=null; hints_flush_period_in_ms=10000; incremental_backups=false; index_interval=null; index_summary_capacity_in_mb=null; index_summary_resize_interval_in_minutes=60; initial_token=null; inter_dc_stream_throughput_outbound_megabits_per_sec=200; inter_dc_tcp_nodelay=false; internode_authenticator=null; internode_compression=dc; internode_recv_buff_size_in_bytes=0; internode_send_buff_size_in_bytes=0; key_cache_keys_to_save=2147483647; key_cache_save_period=14400; key_cache_size_in_mb=null; listen_address=127.0.0.2; listen_interface=null; listen_interface_prefer_ipv6=false; listen_on_broadcast_address=false; max_hint_window_in_ms=10800000; max_hints_delivery_threads=2; max_hints_file_size_in_mb=128; max_mutation_size_in_kb=null; max_streaming_retries=3; max_value_size_in_mb=256; memtable_allocation_type=heap_buffers; memtable_cleanup_threshold=null; memtable_flush_writers=0; memtable_heap_space_in_mb=null; memtable_offheap_space_in_mb=null; min_free_space_per_drive_in_mb=50; native_transport_flush_in_batches_legacy=true; native_transport_max_concurrent_connections=-1; native_transport_max_concurrent_connections_per_ip=-1; native_transport_max_concurrent_requests_in_bytes=-1; native_transport_max_concurrent_requests_in_bytes_per_ip=-1; native_transport_max_frame_size_in_mb=256; native_transport_max_negotiable_protocol_version=-2147483648; native_transport_max_threads=128; native_transport_port=9042; native_transport_port_ssl=null; num_tokens=256; otc_backlog_expiration_interval_ms=200; otc_coalescing_enough_coalesced_messages=8; otc_coalescing_strategy=DISABLED; otc_coalescing_window_us=200; partitioner=org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner; permissions_cache_max_entries=1000; permissions_update_interval_in_ms=-1; permissions_validity_in_ms=2000; phi_convict_threshold=8.0; prepared_statements_cache_size_mb=null; range_request_timeout_in_ms=10000; read_request_timeout_in_ms=5000; repair_session_max_tree_depth=18; request_scheduler=org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.NoScheduler; request_scheduler_id=null; request_scheduler_options=null; request_timeout_in_ms=10000; role_manager=CassandraRoleManager; roles_cache_max_entries=1000; roles_update_interval_in_ms=-1; roles_validity_in_ms=2000; row_cache_class_name=org.apache.cassandra.cache.OHCProvider; row_cache_keys_to_save=2147483647; row_cache_save_period=0; row_cache_size_in_mb=0; rpc_address=127.0.0.2; rpc_interface=null; rpc_interface_prefer_ipv6=false; rpc_keepalive=true; rpc_listen_backlog=50; rpc_max_threads=2147483647; rpc_min_threads=16; rpc_port=9160; rpc_recv_buff_size_in_bytes=null; rpc_send_buff_size_in_bytes=null; rpc_server_type=sync; saved_caches_directory=null; seed_provider=org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider{seeds=127.0.0.1}; server_encryption_options=<REDACTED>; slow_query_log_timeout_in_ms=500; snapshot_before_compaction=false; snapshot_on_duplicate_row_detection=false; ssl_storage_port=7001; sstable_preemptive_open_interval_in_mb=50; start_native_transport=true; start_rpc=false; storage_port=7000; stream_throughput_outbound_megabits_per_sec=200; streaming_keep_alive_period_in_secs=300; streaming_socket_timeout_in_ms=86400000; thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb=15; thrift_max_message_length_in_mb=16; thrift_prepared_statements_cache_size_mb=null; tombstone_failure_threshold=100000; tombstone_warn_threshold=1000; tracetype_query_ttl=86400; tracetype_repair_ttl=604800; transparent_data_encryption_options=org.apache.cassandra.config.TransparentDataEncryptionOptions@5656be13; trickle_fsync=false; trickle_fsync_interval_in_kb=10240; truncate_request_timeout_in_ms=60000; unlogged_batch_across_partitions_warn_threshold=10; user_defined_function_fail_timeout=1500; user_defined_function_warn_timeout=500; user_function_timeout_policy=die; windows_timer_interval=1; write_request_timeout_in_ms=2000] INFO  [main] 2020-08-17 17:31:22,361 DatabaseDescriptor.java:381 - DiskAccessMode 'auto' determined to be mmap, indexAccessMode is mmap INFO  [main] 2020-08-17 17:31:22,366 DatabaseDescriptor.java:439 - Global memtable on-heap threshold is enabled at 503MB INFO  [main] 2020-08-17 17:31:22,367 DatabaseDescriptor.java:443 - Global memtable off-heap threshold is enabled at 503MB INFO  [main] 2020-08-17 17:31:22,538 RateBasedBackPressure.java:123 - Initialized back-pressure with high ratio: 0.9, factor: 5, flow: FAST, window size: 2000. INFO  [main] 2020-08-17 17:31:22,538 DatabaseDescriptor.java:773 - Back-pressure is disabled with strategy org.apache.cassandra.net.RateBasedBackPressure{high_ratio=0.9, factor=5, flow=FAST}. INFO  [main] 2020-08-17 17:31:22,686 JMXServerUtils.java:252 - Configured JMX server at: service:jmx:rmi://127.0.0.1/jndi/rmi://127.0.0.1:7199/jmxrmi INFO  [main] 2020-08-17 17:31:22,700 CassandraDaemon.java:490 - Hostname: DESKTOP-NQ7673H INFO  [main] 2020-08-17 17:31:22,703 CassandraDaemon.java:497 - JVM vendor/version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM/1.8.0_261 INFO  [main] 2020-08-17 17:31:22,709 CassandraDaemon.java:498 - Heap size: 1.968GiB/1.968GiB INFO  [main] 2020-08-17 17:31:22,712 CassandraDaemon.java:503 - Code Cache Non-heap memory: init = 2555904(2496K) used = 5181696(5060K) committed = 5242880(5120K) max = 251658240(245760K) INFO  [main] 2020-08-17 17:31:22,714 CassandraDaemon.java:503 - Metaspace Non-heap memory: init = 0(0K) used = 19412472(18957K) committed = 20054016(19584K) max
    = -1(-1K) INFO  [main] 2020-08-17 17:31:22,738 CassandraDaemon.java:503 - Compressed Class Space Non-heap memory: init = 0(0K) used = 2373616(2317K) committed = 2621440(2560K) max = 1073741824(1048576K) INFO  [main] 2020-08-17 17:31:22,739 CassandraDaemon.java:503 - Par Eden Space Heap memory: init = 279183360(272640K) used = 111694624(109076K) committed = 279183360(272640K) max = 279183360(272640K) INFO  [main] 2020-08-17 17:31:22,740 CassandraDaemon.java:503 - Par Survivor Space Heap memory: init = 34865152(34048K) used = 0(0K) committed = 34865152(34048K) max = 34865152(34048K) INFO  [main] 2020-08-17 17:31:22,743 CassandraDaemon.java:503 - CMS Old Gen Heap memory: init
    = 1798569984(1756416K) used = 0(0K) committed = 1798569984(1756416K) max = 1798569984(1756416K) INFO  [main] 2020-08-17 17:31:22,744 CassandraDaemon.java:505 - Classpath: D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\conf;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\airline-0.6.jar;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\antlr-runtime-3.5.2.jar;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\apache-cassandra-3.11.7.jar;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\apache-cassandra-thrift-3.11.7.jar;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\asm-5.0.4.jar;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\caffeine-2.2.6.jar;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\cassandra-driver-core-3.0.1-shaded.jar;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\commons-cli-1.1.jar;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\commons-codec-1.9.jar;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\commons-lang3-3.1.jar;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\commons-math3-3.2.jar;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\compress-lzf-0.8.4.jar;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\concurrent-trees-2.4.0.jar;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.4.jar;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\disruptor-3.0.1.jar;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\ecj-4.4.2.jar;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\guava-18.0.jar;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\HdrHistogram-2.1.9.jar;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\high-scale-lib-1.0.6.jar;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\hppc-0.5.4.jar;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\jackson-annotations-2.9.10.jar;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\jackson-core-2.9.10.jar;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\jackson-databind-2.9.10.4.jar;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\jamm-0.3.0.jar;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\javax.inject.jar;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\jbcrypt-0.3m.jar;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\jctools-core-1.2.1.jar;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\jflex-1.6.0.jar;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\jna-4.2.2.jar;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\joda-time-2.4.jar;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\json-simple-1.1.jar;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\jstackjunit-0.0.1.jar;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\libthrift-0.9.2.jar;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\logback-classic-1.1.3.jar;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\logback-core-1.1.3.jar;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\lz4-1.3.0.jar;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\metrics-core-3.1.5.jar;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\metrics-jvm-3.1.5.jar;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\metrics-logback-3.1.5.jar;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\netty-all-4.0.44.Final.jar;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\ohc-core-0.4.4.jar;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\ohc-core-j8-0.4.4.jar;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\reporter-config-base-3.0.3.jar;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\reporter-config3-3.0.3.jar;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\sigar-1.6.4.jar;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\snakeyaml-1.11.jar;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\snappy-java-1.1.1.7.jar;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\snowball-stemmer-1.3.0.581.1.jar;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\ST4-4.0.8.jar;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\stream-2.5.2.jar;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\thrift-server-0.3.7.jar;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\build\classes\main;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\build\classes\thrift;D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\jamm-0.3.0.jar INFO  [main] 2020-08-17 17:31:22,747 CassandraDaemon.java:507 - JVM Arguments: [-ea,
    -javaagent:D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\jamm-0.3.0.jar, -Xms2G, -Xmx2G, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:+UseParNewGC, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled, -XX:SurvivorRatio=8, -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -Dlogback.configurationFile=logback.xml, -Djava.library.path=D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\lib\sigar-bin, -Dcassandra.jmx.local.port=7199, -Dcassandra, -Dcassandra-foreground=yes, -Dcassandra.logdir=D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\logs, -Dcassandra.storagedir=D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.7\data] WARN  [main] 2020-08-17 17:31:22,763 StartupChecks.java:169 - JMX is not enabled to receive remote connections. Please see cassandra-env.sh for more info. WARN  [main] 2020-08-17 17:31:22,768 StartupChecks.java:220 - The JVM is not configured to stop on OutOfMemoryError which can cause data corruption. Use one of the following JVM options to configure the behavior on OutOfMemoryError:  -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError,
    -XX:+CrashOnOutOfMemoryError, or -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="<cmd args>;<cmd args>" INFO  [main] 2020-08-17 17:31:22,774 SigarLibrary.java:44 - Initializing SIGAR library
```

Can you pls help me resolve the port issue which is stopping me from running two instances.
In addition, I'll appreciate if you suggest other ways to get this done e.g. options 1 or 2 as I've mentioned in the beginning of my post or GCP or AWS with free account.

Answer (score 4):

Option 2 - using docker - is very easy. This is described in details here: [cassandra - docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/cassandra)
First of all you must increase resources in docker, because default configuration migh be too small for running more than 1-2 nodes - I am using 8 GB RAM and 3 cpu on my laptop and I am able to start 3 nodes of Cassandra simultanously.
[image]

The first step is to create a bridge network which will be used by Cassandra's cluster:

```
docker network create mynet
```

Then start a first node :

```
docker run --name cas1 --network mynet -d cassandra
```

then wait about one minute until the node starts, and then start another node:

```
docker run --name cas2 --network mynet -d  -e CASSANDRA_SEEDS=cas1 cassandra
```

and again, start third node:

```
docker run --name cas3 --network mynet -d  -e CASSANDRA_SEEDS=cas1 cassandra
```

---

Finally start another docker container instance in interactive mode, run cqlsh in it and connect cqlsh to your cluster (to the first node named `cas1`):

```
docker run -it --network mynet --rm cassandra cqlsh cas1
Connected to Test Cluster at cas1:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.7 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]
Use HELP for help.
cqlsh>
```

Comment: Thank you, and will check at the earliest.